# Whenever I commit and push a file to github, a duplicated ending with ~ appears in my local and remote repository

Tags: linux, files, github, file-management

I am a beginner in Linux and I am still navigating my way aroung the terminal and file manipulation. Whenever I commit and push a file to my github, a duplicate is created alongside it. Can I delete the duplicate without any implications? Also how do I prevent this from happening again?

An example is I push "filename1" and "filename1~" appears alongside it in both local and remote repositories. And filename1~, the duplicate, is always empty though filename1, the original, contains text.

Comment: Which IDE are you using to modify your file it's perhaps a backup done while editing.

Comment: @admstg I'm using a vagrant vm with ubuntu installed

Comment: And how do you edit the file content? What  IDE or text editor are you using? (Vim,kate, neovim, gedit, some jetbrains ide...)

Comment: Using emacs editor

Comment: I don't think that behavior is about `git` but from `emacs`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151945/how-do-i-control-how-emacs-makes-backup-files).  If you want to avoid emacs from generating backups you should add this line: `(setq make-backup-files nil)` in  the `.emacs` file (I do not know where can be located this file in your case, maybe under `/home/user/.emacs`? If it is not then check [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html) )